# calculate the sum of n initial terms of the sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have problem with finding the formula for the sum of $n$ initial terms of
$$a(n)=n \cdot 2^n.$$

I only wrote the first few terms $\displaystyle a(1)=2$, $a(2)=8$, $a(3)=24$, $a(4)=64$

Comment: I don't understand, what are you asking for? You already wrote out the first couple of terms, and you have the generic form of an $n$-th term. Do you want to *sum* the first $n$ terms?

Comment: yes, that's what I am asking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Note that if we take the usual geometric series
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n x^k = \frac{1 - x^{k+1}}{1-x}, \quad \forall x \neq 0,
$$
we can differentiate it with respect to $x$ to get
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \sum_{k=0}^n x^k
  =  \sum_{k=1}^n k x^{k-1}
  =  \frac{1}{x} \sum_{k=1}^n k x^k
$$
on the left-hand side. Now differentiate the right-hand side using the quotient rule and you should be able to take it from there.

Comment: seems a bit complicated

Comment: No one said life was supposed to always be easy :-). On the other hand, this is a *very* useful and often needed result. It helps to derive it once and keep in your toolbox forever.

Comment: OK, thanks for help

Comment: Complicated?  gt gave a beautiful and, in retrospect, obvious solution.  When solutions look like this, you're living the good life.